# Will pseudo force effect buoyant force in a liquid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics

Imagine a body in a tub which is in a lift. When the lift is stationary, the body is floating. If the lift accelerates upwards with a constant acceleration, what will happen to the buoyancy? Will its value change or not?

I do not think it shouldn't. But my friend says it will. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lift is a somewhat complicated example because a lift can be stationary, moving at constant speed or accelerating (or decelerating) and this affects the forces felt by the objects in it. Perhaps a better example would be to ask if the system changes as the force of gravity is changed, e.g. by raising the system to different heights.

Having said this, it doesn't make any difference. [Archimedes' principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle) tells us that the floating object displaces a volume of water $V$ where the weight of this water $V\rho_w g$ equals the weight of the object $mg$ so we can write an expression for the volume of water displaced:

$$ V = \frac{m}{\rho_w} $$

Note that the acceleration due to gravity, $g$, cancels out so the bouyancy is not affected by changes in the gravity (or acceleration in a lift).

There may be small effects that become important at very high accelerations. For example at high accelerations the floating object my be compressed by the pressure exerted by the water and this would reduce its bouyancy. This is unlikely to be significant in a lift.

Comment: Firstly, i am that "friend". Secondly, i find this question, therefore, the answer, vague. What exactly is buoyancy? When i was quizzing rohin, i said BUOYANT FORCE. I think, @JohnRennie, u mean that volume of fluid displaced, is equal to volume of object submerged and that does not change even if acceleration due to gravity is different? If so, i do not disagree. But archimedes principle also states that buoyant force is equal to WEIGHT of fluid displaced. That will change if a lift is accelerating. Yes, he meant an upward acceleration when he talked about the lift.

Comment: @SaurabhRaje: fair enough. I assumed the OP meant the volume of fluid displaced, and we both agree that won't change.

Comment: but now that u know what the question is, what is ur opinion? Will the buoyant force change?

Comment: can you please answer the new question?

Comment: @SaurabhRaje: if you want to post a question on this site I'll answer it, but I'm not getting involved in an arguament between you and Rohinb97.